# Trying to implement methods from a different class

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am using the TabLayout to switch between different tabs in the app. That part of the app works, however, I had to create a new class that handles the calculator tab. I have the code for the calculator to work, however, I can't figure out how to call the methods from the `calculatorfunctionFragment` to the `MainActivity`.

I have tried using the code in the Main Activity:
calling the calculatorFunctionFragment

```
        calculatorfunctionFragment cls2 = new calculatorfunctionFragment();

        cls2.startActivity(getIntent());
```

and I have even tried to adding `cls2.getIntent()`
Both are not working.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //declaring the Tab layout and other app functions for the app
    public TabLayout tabLayout;
    public AppBarLayout appBarLayout;
    public ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Now making the tab and appBar layout and viewPager active
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout_id);
        appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appabar);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_id);

        ViewPageAdapter adapter = new ViewPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        //adding Fragment and Titles for the ViewPagerAdapter to find and populate
        adapter.AddFragment(new calculatorFragment(),"Calculator Page");
        adapter.AddFragment(new formulapageFragment(),"Formula Page");
        adapter.AddFragment(new webFragment(),"Web Page");


        // adapter Setup
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        //calling the CalculatorFunctionFragment

        calculatorfunctionFragment cls2 = new calculatorfunctionFragment();

        cls2.startActivity(getIntent());


    }
```

I expected the Main Activity to work with the calculator fragment to work

Comment: How it does not work? Can you show your `calculatorfunctionFragment` code?

Comment: Yes, I can. I can add it to GitHub that way it's easier to see it in full

Comment: The link is here: https://github.com/KarltonSen/calculatorfunctionFragment

Comment: Are you trying to start a new activity in `onCreate()`? How does your app work?

Answer (score 0):

Friend - your class called `calculatorfunctionFragment` is a class that extends `AppCompatActivity`. So it is not a fragment, it is an Activity. You do not start an Activity by calling `new` on it.

It seems like you need to review the documentation and work through some "getting started" guides to understand how Activities work and how you launch them.

Please [review the official docs on Activities](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/intro-activities) and then Google for "how to start a new Activity".

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'll take a look at the docs on Activities and hope that works.